# Binary (Hexa, Bin) NOT in Excel

Tags: excel

i am currently doing my homework cryptography **SHA-1**. To make it easier, i use Excel since if i use MS word, that will take days to finish. I have some problems though in doing it in Excel 2016.

One problem is that i need to know how to use Binary NOT in Excel. For example, if i input the hexadecimal:

12345678

It should return the value into this:

FFFFEDCBA987 (<= Since it is NOT/Inverse from above value)

Can anyone help me in finding the formula??? (Each cell or 1 cell only is appreciated) Thank you very much.

Note: If it is possible, just need the formula, not the code function in VBA excel since i am very noob about it. Thank you.

Comment: `12345678` must be dec not hex and `FFFFEDCBA987` is almost assuredly hex and not bin.

Comment: I know, but think of the value above as Hexa :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pure Excel formula solution is a little bit complicated but possible:

[image]

Formulas:

in `B1` copied to right until `Q1`:

```
=RIGHT("0000"&HEX2BIN(MID($A1,COLUMNS($A:A),1)),4)
```

`COLUMNS($A:A)` will count up: 1 ($A:A), 2 ($A:B), 3 ($A:C), ... 16 ($A:P) depending on which column it is copied rightwards.
So `MID($A1,COLUMNS($A:A),1)` will get *one* digit from `A1` depending on which column it is copied rightwards.
`HEX2BIN(MID($A1,COLUMNS($A:A),1))` will convert that one digti to binary. But it will not return leading zeros. So for example `HEX2BIN("3")` will be "11" and not "0011".
But for the next step we need 4 binary digits. So `=RIGHT("0000"&HEX2BIN(MID($A1,COLUMNS($A:A),1)),4)` will add those leading zeros up to 4 binary digits.
So in the whole the formula will get every single digit of  `A1` as a 4 digit binary.

Edit: `HEX2BIN` has a second parameter for giving the digits count. So no need for the `RIGHT("0000"&HEX2BIN(...),4)`

```
=HEX2BIN(MID($A1,COLUMNS($A:A),1),4)
```

will also work.

in `B2` copied to right until `Q2`:

```
=--NOT(--MID(B1,1,1))&--NOT(--MID(B1,2,1))&--NOT(--MID(B1,3,1))&--NOT(--MID(B1,4,1))
```

This formula will take every single digit of the 4 digit binary from the cell above and negate it. The `--` parts (`*-1*-1`) are necessary to force implicit conversion from string to numeric.

in `B3` copied to right until `Q3`:

```
=BIN2HEX(B2)
```

In `A3`:

```
=B3&C3&D3&E3&F3&G3&H3&I3&J3&K3&L3&M3&N3&O3&P3&Q3
```

Column `A` must be formatted as `Text`.

After this you can copy the rows `1:3` down in rows `5:7`.  Then input the needed Hex in `A5`. Note, you must input always 16 digits.

From Excel 2013 there is a native `BITXOR` function: https://support.office.com/en-us/Article/BITXOR-function-c81306a1-03f9-4e89-85ac-b86c3cba10e4

So `Mark PM`'s solution should work also with a maximum of 12 hex digits (values up to 16^12-1 = 2^48-1). But I can't try it because I have not Excel 2013.

Comment: I understand. Ill give it a try :)Thanks. Ill tell you soon about the formulas

Comment: It works. Thank you for the formula. But i have a question that needs to be asked. 

=RIGHT("0000"&HEX2BIN(MID($A1,COLUMNS($A:A),1)),4)

Whats the explanation of "0000" for? Why is that being used? Why is COLUMNS ($A:A) should be blocked? I am still hard to understand the formula.
@AxelRichter

Comment: I see that if it is not 16 digits then the formula is wrong. Thank you for it.

**How do i use for only 8 digits of Hexa???**

Comment: @ Wisely Jansen Rocketeers: See my explanations. For less digits just use less helper columns. For 8 digits use `B:I`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use BITXOR to do that:

```
=BITXOR(12345678,HEX2DEC("FFFFFFFF"))
```

Add more FF for your bit length.

Comment: BITXOR ...? There is no [matlab] tag.

Comment: Are you looking for an Excel formula or VBA?

Comment: ① Wrong persona to ask ② The OP states non-VBA solution in the post.

Comment: Ill try to input that. Thank you :) Im just looking for the formula. No VBA cause i am confused with that :)